# Converting array of numbers to json in perl, getting array of strings

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to convert an array of numbers to json:

```
   $json = to_json("numbers_array" => \@numbers_array);
   print $json;
```

but the output I'm getting is:

```
  {"numbers_array" => ["1","2","3"] }
```

I'm building up the array by adding elements using push(). How do I convert to json and retain the numeric type, so that the output is:

```
  {"numbers_array" => [1,2,3]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`JSON` documentation](http://p3rl.org/JSON):

---

> You can force the type to be a number by numifying it:

```
   my $x = "3"; # some variable containing a string
   $x += 0;     # numify it, ensuring it will be dumped as a number
   $x *= 1;     # same thing, the choice is yours.
```

---

I would try something like this:

```
    $json = to_json({numbers_array => [map { $_ + 0 } @numbers_array]});
    print $json;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to earlier answers: it's not a question of the *definition* of your data but of *usage*.

From the [JSON::XS pod](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#other-references):

> JSON::XS will encode […] scalars that have last been used in a string context before encoding as JSON strings, and anything else as number value

Consider this piece of code:

```perl
use JSON::XS;
my $numbers = [123,124,125];
print "A number: $numbers->[1]\n";            #<- use 2nd entry in string context.
print JSON::XS->new->encode ($numbers)."\n";
```

It prints:

```
A number: 124
[123,"124",125]
```

Would you have expected that number *124* be encoded as string?
Beware!

(I learned that the hard way chasing a [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297896/understanding-heisenbug-example-different-precision-in-registers-vs-main-memory) that only showed up when I had some debug logging active.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use JSON;

my @array;
for my $number ( (1..5) ) {
    push @array, $number;
}
say to_json( {"number_array" => \@array} );
```

And here's my result:

```
{"number_array":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

That's what you want. Right?

Let's change my `push` from `push @array , $number;` to `push @array "$number";` where `$number` is in quotes as if it's a string:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use JSON;

my @array;
for my $number ( (1..5) ) {
    push @array, "$number";
}
say to_json( {"number_array" => \@array} );
```

Now I get:

```
{"number_array":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
```

Somehow JSON was able to detect that these *numbers* were pushed in as strings. Let me loop again and add a zero to each element:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use JSON;

my @array;
for my $number ( (1..5) ) {
    push @array, "$number";
}

@array  = map { $_ += 0 } @array; #Add a 0 to each element

say to_json( {"number_array" => \@array} );
```

Back to:

```
{"number_array":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Looks like you have to add a zero to each element of your array to convert the string back to a numeric value.